Docker build fails with "configure: error: write failure creating ./config.status"
I am currently experiencing some problems while build docker images on my local machine.
I'm running docker 26.1.3, docker-compose 2.27.0 on Linux Mint 21.3
I could build my containers until recently. Yesterday I noticed I could not build a new one, and now I have the same problem with all docker compose up or docker build .
The first steps of the build are running, but then there is an error.
The same error occurs when trying different commands : configure: error: write failure creating ./config.status
I could build the containers before, and I still can build it on other machines.
The user I belongs to the "docker" group and have the right permissions.
While trying RUN pecl install xdebug :
10.08 creating libtool
10.12 /tmp/pear/temp/xdebug/configure: line 12027:  1472 Killed                  chmod +x "$ofile"
10.14 appending configuration tag "CXX" to libtool
10.16 /tmp/pear/temp/xdebug/configure: line 15083:  1482 Killed                  chmod +x "$ofile"
10.38 configure: patching config.h.in
10.39 configure: creating ./config.status
10.39 /tmp/pear/temp/xdebug/configure: line 15783:  1627 Killed                  chmod +x $CONFIG_STATUS
10.47 configure: error: write failure creating ./config.status
10.52 ERROR: `/tmp/pear/temp/xdebug/configure --with-php-config=/usr/local/bin/php-config' failedfailed to solve: process "/bin/sh -c pecl install xdebug" did not complete successfully: exit code: 1
failed to solve: process "/bin/sh -c pecl install xdebug" did not complete successfully: exit code: 11

While trying RUN docker docker-php-ext-install mysql
10.47 configure: error: write failure creating ./config.statusconfigure: error: write failure creating ./config.status10.08
10.08 creating libtool
10.12 /tmp/pear/temp/xdebug/configure: line 12027:  1472 Killed                  chmod +x "$ofile"
10.14 appending configuration tag "CXX" to libtool
10.16 /tmp/pear/temp/xdebug/configure: line 15083:  1482 Killed                  chmod +x "$ofile"
10.38 configure: patching config.h.in
10.39 configure: creating ./config.status
10.39 /tmp/pear/temp/xdebug/configure: line 15783:  1627 Killed                  chmod +x $CONFIG_STATUS
10.47 configure: error: write failure creating ./config.status
10.52 ERROR: `/tmp/pear/temp/xdebug/configure --with-php-config=/usr/local/bin/php-config' failedfailed to solve: process "/bin/sh -c pecl install xdebug" did not complete successfully: exit code: 1
failed to solve: process "/bin/sh -c pecl install xdebug" did not complete successfully: exit code: 1113.10 creating libtool
13.14 ./configure: line 10590:  1265 Killed                  chmod +x "$ofile"
13.17 appending configuration tag "CXX" to libtool
13.18 ./configure: line 13635:  1275 Killed                  chmod +x "$ofile"
13.36 configure: creating ./config.status
13.38 ./configure: line 14280:  1386 Killed                  chmod +x $CONFIG_STATUS
13.48 configure: error: write failure creating ./config.status
------
failed to solve: process "/bin/sh -c docker-php-ext-install mysql" did not complete successfully: exit code: 1

While trying RUN docker-php-ext-configure something :
16.30 creating libtool
16.33 ./configure: line 11263:  1173 Killed                  chmod +x "$ofile"
16.36 appending configuration tag "CXX" to libtool
16.37 ./configure: line 14327:  1183 Killed                  chmod +x "$ofile"
16.54 configure: patching config.h.in
16.55 configure: creating ./config.status
16.56 ./configure: line 15025:  1295 Killed                  chmod +x $CONFIG_STATUS
16.65 configure: error: write failure creating ./config.status
------
failed to solve: process "/bin/sh -c docker-php-ext-configure zip &&     docker-php-ext-install mysqli pdo pdo_mysql zip soap &&     docker-php-
ext-install dom xmlwriter simplexml &&     docker-php-ext-enable pdo_mysql" did not complete successfully: exit code: 1   

My disk space is a lot more than required, The ram is not full when I hit these errors, the CPU is ok... I tried to clear all the caches, containers from docker with the docker prune commands. I uninstalled completely docker and reinstalled it... but I don't know where to search now...
Has someone hit that problem too ? how to solve it please ?
Note : If I remove the lines that return these errors, the build completes ok.
The docker-php-ext-install commands return the same error if I build the container and then run it from inside the container
Here is a Dockerfile example, where the problem exists:
FROM php:8.1-apache

RUN apt-get update -y && \
    apt-get install -y \
       libmcrypt-dev \
        libssl-dev \
        git    \
        zlib1g-dev \
        libzip-dev \
        libxml2-dev

RUN a2enmod rewrite

RUN docker-php-ext-configure zip && \
    docker-php-ext-install mysqli pdo pdo_mysql zip soap && \
    docker-php-ext-install dom xmlwriter simplexml && \
    docker-php-ext-enable pdo_mysql

RUN curl -sS https://getcomposer.org/installer | php -- --install-dir=/usr/local/bin --filename=composer

WORKDIR /var/www/html
COPY . /var/www/html

RUN composer install

RUN cp .env.example .env
RUN php artisan key:generate

Edit :
Partitions and disk space
/var/lib/docker is not on a separate partition. and it look like there is enough space : Here is the return of docker run --rm alpine df -h /
Unable to find image 'alpine:latest' locally latest: Pulling from library/alpine d25f557d7f31: P
ull complete Digest: sha256:77726ef6b57ddf65bb551896826ec38bc3e53f75cdde31354fbffb4f25238ebd 
Status: Downloaded newer image for alpine:latest 

Filesystem Size Used 
Available Use% Mounted on overlay 467.9G 61.0G 383.1G 14% / ``` – 

journalctl does not return error
journalctl seems to return some warnings like : kernel : [ UFW BLOCK ] but nothing more. I since disabled UFW to make sure it wasn´t the problem. There is no error
I dont know if this is relevant, but here are the logs :
mai 28 16:41:30 PC systemd-udevd[25504]: vethd506f2f: Could not set offload features, ignoring: No such device 
mai 28 16:41:30 PC avahi-daemon[766]: Withdrawing address record for fe80::4ccb:6aff:fe1e:851f on veth90428ce. 
mai 28 16:41:30 PC systemd-udevd[25504]: Using default interface naming scheme 'v249'. 
mai 28 16:41:31 PC systemd[1]: run-docker-netns-d072f74bd51b.mount: Deactivated successfully. 
mai 28 16:41:31 PC NetworkManager[771]: <info> [1716907291.3206] device (veth90428ce): released from master device docker0 

Edit
After some research, it appears that everything was fine, and the SOC prevented some commands to run after a policy update.

It would help to see a Dockerfile that reproduces this behavior.

You're right. I just edited the original post.
thanks

Are there any system logs that happen concurrently with these failures from Docker (looking at journalctl)? Is /var/lib/docker on a separate partition from /? Are you certain that /var/lib/docker has sufficient space? What does docker run --rm alpine df -h / show?

It is better to update your question when adding requested information, rather than adding comments. As you have no doubt noticed, you cannot usefully format things in comments.

You are right. I updated the original question.
Thank you for your time.

@larsks,
After some research, it appears that everything was fine, and the SOC prevented some commands to run after a policy update... thank you for your time !
